# Struts 2 : two page which Forward to the same page after post form. how can I return the calling page (interceptor scope or hidden value)

Tags: java, struts2, interceptor

When we can use hidden value.
For example : two actions (`list` and `listAdvanced`) which forward to the same page `result.jsp`, I want to return to the calling page to modify some properties.

My problem is: I don't know which method to manage this, using scope `interceptor` or hidden value to pass the value of the calling page?

Comment: By separate actions, do you mean separate `Action` classes (classes that extend `ActionSupport`) or two methods of the same Action class? If they're in the same class or if they can be put in the same class, using a hidden variable will suffice.

Comment: Thank you for replay, you right, i mean two method in the some Action class . i want to use hidden value but i was confused. Thank you again

Comment: Hidden param, or session.